# Detecting browser close [X] event (perform on serverside)

Tags: asp.net, browser

I want to Detect user activity, when the user click the browser [x]. It dosn't matter if I use java scripts or without javascript as long as I perform it on the serverside (codebehind) because I have a process that  I need to accomplish on a serverside before the page is closing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know for sure if the user is closing the browser (pressing [x]) or not. You can only know whether the user is leaving a certain page. You can capture that with the `window.onunload` event. This event will fire when the user presses [x], but it will also fire when the user clicks a link on the page. That's what I mean when I say you can't know whether the user clicked [x] for sure. It might still do the job for you though.

Some details about the onunload event can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp). You can execute a fire-and-forget ajax call to the server to do whatever you need to do serverside.

```
window.onunload = function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      async: false, // You need this to make sure the AJAX call will complete
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/some/url'
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks you for reply. it's really helpful. trying to study about it, and make some expirement